# ListInterpolation and extrapolation: order has been reduced,

Tags: plotting, list-manipulation, interpolation, parametric-functions

I have a following [`ListPlot`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/ListPlot.html) and [`ListInterpolation`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/ListInterpolation.html),

```
ListPlot[{{0.4, 2},{0.8,3.4351},{1.1,11.5229},{1.2, 25.7315},{1.3,39.4621},{1.5,55.7524},{1.7,65.5547},{1.9, 72.061}, {2,74.5191},{2.2,78.3138},{2.4,81.0551},{2.6,83.082},{2.8,84.609}}]

ListInterpolation[{{0.4, 2},{0.8,3.4351},{1.1,11.5229},{1.2, 25.7315},{1.3,39.4621},{1.5,55.7524},{1.7,65.5547},{1.9, 72.061}, {2,74.5191},{2.2,78.3138},{2.4,81.0551},{2.6,83.082},{2.8,84.609}}]
```

I get the error

> ListInterpolation::inhr: Requested order is too high; order has been
> reduced to {3,1}.

[image]

**Why the order has been reduced in the `ListInterpolation`?**

**How to plot the interpolated function with same x and y axis?**

**How to extrapolate it till the value is 90 on y-axis?**

Comment: You should read the documentation for [`ListInterpolation`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/ListInterpolation.html) to see how it is supposed to be used: The $y$-values go to the first argument, and the $x$-values to the second. For example: ``ListInterpolation[data[[All, 2]], data[[All, 1]]`` where ``data = {{0.4, 2}, {0.8, 3.4351}, ... }`` is your list.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[`ListInterpolation`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/ListInterpolation.html) does not expect a list of $\{x_i, y_i\}$ values. The way you are using it, *Mathematica* interprets it as a 2D array, and in one dimension you have only two data points, not enough for a higher order interpolation.

If you want to interpolate ${x_i, y_i}$ data, you can do the ${x_i}$ and ${y_i}$ arrays separately and then use [`ParametricPlot`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/ParametricPlot.html) as I'm showing here.

```
Show[
    ListPlot[data],
    ParametricPlot[
        Evaluate[
            Map[
                ListInterpolation[#,{0,1},InterpolationOrder->3][x]&,
                Transpose[data]
            ]            
        ]
        , {x, 0, 1}
    ]
]
```

[image]

If you want to extrapolate, just expand the $x$ range

```
Show[
ParametricPlot[
Evaluate[ListInterpolation[#,{0,1},InterpolationOrder->3][x]& /@ Transpose[data]]
,{x,-0.1,1.5}
,AspectRatio->1
,PlotTheme->"Scientific"
],
ListPlot[data]
,Epilog-> {Gray, Line[{{-10,90}, {10,90}}]}
]
```

[image]

Otherwise, you can specify the $x_i$ values, like $\{\{x_i\}, y_i\}$ , as shown in the excellent answer by  @BobHanlon (+1). ([see doc](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/ListInterpolation.html?view=all#:%7E:text=The%20x%20values%20may%20be%20included%20in%20the%20data%20directly%3A))

[image]

Answer (score 4):

```
Clear["Global`*"]

data = {{0.4, 2}, {0.8, 3.4351}, {1.1, 11.5229}, {1.2, 25.7315}, {1.3,
     39.4621}, {1.5, 55.7524}, {1.7, 65.5547}, {1.9, 72.061}, {2, 
    74.5191}, {2.2, 78.3138}, {2.4, 81.0551}, {2.6, 83.082}, {2.8, 
    84.609}};

lplt = ListPlot[data, PlotStyle -> Red];

f = ListInterpolation[{{#[[1]]}, #[[2]]} & /@ data];

xmax = NSolveValues[f[x] == 90, x][[1]] // Quiet

(* 3.59917 *)

Show[
  Plot[f[x], {x, 0.4, xmax},
   GridLines -> {None, {90}}],
  lplt] // Quiet
```

[image]